# How to find the range of composite numbers within two integers similar to sympy.primerange(a,b)

Tags: python, sympy

I was tinkering with the idea of the [polar plotting of prime numbers](https://youtu.be/EK32jo7i5LQ?si=bRxmo1Xmyv_YSC_E) and I'm currently using the code below to calculate and plot everything.

Unsure what detail to provide, so I'll provide all of it. I'm using JupyterLab from Anaconda and following everything nearly to a tea from [this website](https://jaketae.github.io/study/prime-spirals/).

I wanted to tinker around with the idea of plotting all composite numbers within a range instead of all prime numbers within a range, much like `sympy.primerange` does. There are few tools for composite numbers as opposed to prime numbers and I wanted to see if there was a workaround to this problem.

```
import math
import sympy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format='retina'
plt.style.use('dark_background')
```

then

```
def get_coordinate(num):
    return num * np.cos(num), num * np.sin(num)
```

and

```
def create_plot(nums, figsize=13.5, s=8, show_annot=True):
    nums = np.array(list(nums))
    x, y = get_coordinate(nums)
    plt.figure(figsize=(figsize, figsize))
    plt.axis("on")
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=s)
    plt.show()
```

then

```
primes = sympy.primerange(a, b)
create_plot(primes)
```

I've tried `sympy.composite` but I consistently received errors and could not figure out how to make it a range. I've also attempted to copy-paste a database of composite numbers which was against the spirit of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So, what problems do you see?  If I include the `get_coordinate` function from that web site and provide values for a and b, it works just fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you share your `sympy.composite` code that is giving the error? What error are you getting?

Comment: Also, you said you're going to give everything because you're not sure what to give. If the issue is just with `sympy.composite` then you only need to share that part of the code. The use case and everything else are irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution would be to iterate through `range` and `sympy.primerange` simultaneously, discarding the primes. That way you don't need to store them all in memory at once, and don't have to sort them.

```py
from sympy import primerange

def compositerange(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        start, end = 0, a
    else:
        start, end = a, b

    primegen = primerange(start, end)
    prime = next(primegen, end)

    for num in range(start, end):
        if prime < num:
            prime = next(primegen, end)
        if num != prime:
            yield num
```

Usage:

```py
>>> print(list(compositerange(10, 22)))
[10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21]
```

Comment: Congratulations on taking my hint and running with it.  It took a minute's thought to convince myself that `if prime < num` didn't need to be a `while`.

Answer (score 1):

Any number greater than or equal to 2 is either prime or composite.  So just take the set of numbers in the range and remove the set of primes.

```
a = 2
b = 100
composite_range = sorted(set(range(a,b)) - set(sympy.primerange(a,b)))
```

Comment: This requires holding all the values in memory at once AND also adds the n log n overhead of sorting them.

Comment: @DillonDavis there were no efficiency constraints listed in the question.  If sets were guaranteed to maintain order like dictionaries do the sorting would be unnecessary, and depending on the OP's application it may not need to be sorted anyway.  But I wanted to be thorough.  There's a variation on this general idea that doesn't have those disadvantages, but it's a little more complicated - I leave it to someone else to come up with that.

Answer (score 0):

The [`sympy.composite`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.generate.composite) function does not produce a range of values like `sympy.primerange`. Instead, you provide `n` and it returns the `n`th composite number. To get the first, say, 50 composite numbers, you would need to call the function for `range(1,51)`. This can be done using list comprehension.

```py
import sympy

N = 50
composite_range = [sympy.composite(n) for n in range(1, N+1)]
print(composite_range) # [4, 6, 8, ..., 68, 69, 70]
```